# Changing theme = change home page for mobile visitors?

Tags: redirect, mobile

I'm trying to create mobile-friendly version for a wp site. I'm using the "any mobile theme switcher" to switch to an alternative (mobile) theme which works well.

I have also created some alternative key pages (home, contact & news) which are heavily edited (shorter) versions of the desktop theme content and added these to a mobile-only menu. Again - this is working well.

The problem I'm trying to solve is how to avoid someone using a mobile device landing on the desktop version of the home page?

I can't see a way of setting a different home / front page within my mobile theme files so..

Can mobile devices be re-directed to my alternative "mobile homepage" instead? And If at all possible,  retain the option to view the full desktop version if desired.

I see the codex describes useful  bits of code, but I need help to make them all work together. In human terms, I think what I need is something that does this -

If is home page,
And if is mobile,
Redirect to http://mysite.com/mobile-homepage

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cobbled together the following code from Pontus's answer and the answer to a slightly different problem here on WP Answers - This works alongside my mobile theme switching plugin, so when a mobile user visits the site, they are redirected to a new set of "mobile-friendly" pages and see my new responsive mobile theme, together with a collapsible mobile page menu :)

```
function so16165211_mobile_home_redirect(){
if( wp_is_mobile() && is_front_page() ){
   wp_redirect( '/mobile-home' ); 
    exit;
}
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'so16165211_mobile_home_redirect' );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a simple function for this, check if is mobile (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_is_mobile). and redirect with `wp_redirect()` http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect

```
add_action('wp_head', 'redirect_mobile');
function redirect_mobile()
{
   if ( wp_is_mobile() ) 
   {
       wp_redirect( 'http://url' ); 
       exit; 
   }
}
```

This is untested but should work.
Add it to your themes `functions.php` file.

Comment: Thanks Pontus - Heading in the right direction I think. I added that to my mobile theme's functions.php, but Iphone can't complete - "too many redirects". Probably a clash with the theme swap plugin I'm using - I'll investigate further...

Comment: ... No luck I'm afraid. Uninstalled the plugin. Then tried moving your script over to the standard desktop theme instead, but safari's still freaking out about "too many redirects". It's only 1, isn't it?!!

Comment: Think Pontus may have inspired me towards a practical solution. If anyone can see a problem with what I'm doing, or suggest a better way, please let me know - Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Similar but without redirection:

```
function template_choose() {

  $part = wp_is_mobile() ? 'mobile' : null;

  if( is_front_page() ) {

    get_template_part( 'home', $part );

    // if not mobile search (in this order) for
    // {$childthemepath}/home.php
    // {themepath}/home.php

    // if mobile search (in this order) for
    // {$childthemepath}/home-mobile.php
    // {$themepath}/home-mobile.php
    // {$childthemepath}/home.php
    // {$themepath}/home.php
    exit();

  } elseif ( is_page() ) { // same logic can be used with different Conditional Tags

    get_template_part( 'page', $part );
    exit();

  }

}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'template_choose' );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I'll try and find time to give it a go over the weekend if possible - Thanks